# How can add a column that shows the day of the week in BigQuery?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, dayofweek, weekday

Im looking to show the day of the week that pertains to the date in my table. The table is under `bellabeat-case-study-2-376122.fitbit_data.daily_activity` and the column I'm pulling from is ActivityDate.  I'm looking to create a column titled DayofWeek.

I've attempted to create a column and insert the data into the column, but it keeps coming back null for the results.

````
##Created a column
ALTER TABLE `bellabeat-case-study-2-376122.fitbit_data.daily_activity`
ADD COLUMN DayofWeek INT64;```

##Attempted to insert the data
INSERT INTO `bellabeat-case-study-2-376122.fitbit_data.daily_activity` (DayofWeek)
SELECT EXTRACT(DAYOFWEEK FROM ActivityDate)
FROM `bellabeat-case-study-2-376122.fitbit_data.daily_activity`
````

Comment: You don't want to `INSERT`, you want to `UPDATE`: `UPDATE bellabeat-case-study-2-376122.fitbit_data.daily_activity SET DayofWeek =  EXTRACT(DAYOFWEEK FROM ActivityDate)`. That being said, your `INSERT` should have still worked, but it would have created a set of new records equal in row count to your existing table (essentially doubling the rows each time you run it).

Answer (score 1):

As @JNevill mentioned in the comments:

You don't want to `INSERT`, you want to `UPDATE`:

```sql
UPDATE bellabeat-case-study-2-376122.fitbit_data.daily_activity SET DayofWeek =  EXTRACT(DAYOFWEEK FROM ActivityDate)
```

That being said, your `INSERT` should have still worked, but it would have created a set of new records equal in row count to your existing table (essentially doubling the rows each time you run it).

Posting the answer as *community wiki* for the benefit of the community that might encounter this use case in the future.

Feel free to edit this answer for additional information.